# How do you use form objects to edit another class instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object, oop, model-view-controller

I need to be able to create and edit instances of the class `User` through a form object called `UserForm`. The form is not persisted, the `User` is saved using the form `save` method.

I got the new/create actions working but because the `UserForm` is not persisted (doesn't have an `id`) I don't know how to load up an existing `User` to edit through the `UserForm`.

How do I "populate" the `UserForm` object with existing `User` data? I tried using the url `id` to load up a `User` but the form fields are still not populated with the `User` data.

*UserForm.rb*

```
class UserForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :email

  before_validation :build_user

  def initialize(params = {})
   super(params)
   @account = Account.find(account_id)
   @user = User.find(user_id)
  end

  def build_user
    @user ||= User.new do |user|
      user.fname = fname
      user.lname = lname
      user.email = email
    end
  end
    
  def save
    user.account_id = @account.id
    user.save
  end
end
```

*UsersController.rb*

```
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
  def new
    @user_form = UserForm.new(account_id: current_account.id)
  end

  def create
    @user_form = UserForm.new(user_form_params)
    
    if @user = @user_form.save
      flash[:success] = "User created"
      redirect_to admin_user_path(@user)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end   
    
    
  def edit
    @user = current_account.users.find(params[:id])
    @user_form = UserForm.new(user: @user)
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_form_params)
      flash[:success] = "User updated"
      redirect_to admin_user_path(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

*new/edit form.html.erb*

```
<%= simple_form_for @user_form, url: admin_users_path do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :fname  %>
    <%= f.input :lname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    
end
```

**Problem:**

I can create a new `User` through the form object, but I can't load and edit the same `User` through the `UserForm` because the form is not populated with the existing `User` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) so that your form object wraps the underlying user instead of duplicating the attributes:

```
class UserForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_reader :user
  delegate :fname, :lname, :email, :account, to: :user

  # Just an example of how the validation uses delegation
  validates :fname, presence: true

  def initialize(object, **attributes)
    case object
    when User
      @user = object
    when Account
      @user = object.users.new(**attributes)
    end
  end

  def save
    # this triggers the validation callbacks
    return false unless valid?
    @user.save
  end

  def update(**attributes)
    @user.assign_attributes(**attributes)
    save
  end

  def to_model
    @user
  end
end
```

Instead of abusing the validation callbacks to perform assignment just pass the attributes to the underlying model.

```
module Admin
  class UsersController < AdminController
    before_action :set_user, except: [:new, :index, :create]

    def new
      @user_form = UserForm.new(current_account)
    end

    def create
      @user_form = UserForm.new(current_account, **user_form_params)
      if @user_form.save
        flash[:success] = "User created"
        redirect_to [:admin, @user_form]
      else
        render "new"
      end
    end

    def edit
      @user_form = UserForm.new(@user)
    end

    def update
      @user_form = UserForm.new(@user)
      if @user_form.update(**user_form_params)
        flash[:success] = "User updated"
        redirect_to [:admin, @user_form]
      else
        render "edit"
      end
    end

    private 

    def set_user
      @user = current_account.users.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end
```

### Some notes:

Avoid `params = {}` and use real keyword arguments. Do not declare nested classes/modules with the scope resultion operator `::`. It leads to autoloading bugs and suprising constant lookups.

Use associations instead of assigning ids directly. This will fire the callbacks on the assocation and avoids leaking the implementation details of your models into the controller layer.

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  # ...
end
```

Your `save` method should most likely have the same return signature as the object your are wrapping and return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that

```
attr_accessor :fname, :lname, :email
```

does not make sense because you have e.g. no `fname` attributes on the form.

Try something like

```
delegate_missing_to :user
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/Module%3Adelegate_missing_to

Also you probably don't have `user_id` and `account_id` attributes in your initializer. So either you have to access them via `params[:user_id]` or also specify attribute readers for them.